# How can I copy a website from GoDaddy cPanel to my Mac

Tags: web-hosting, javascript, localhost, sql

I want to move a small working website to my Mac for testing and experimenting. There is a small database with the website that will need to be accessed locally as well. The website is currently hosted on GoDaddy and works fine. I had a developer help build it, but he's unable to assist right now.

How do I do this? The files in the website are mostly JS and PHP.

Comment: We'd really need to know what database you're using since cPanel can use several different types of databases (though MySQL is the most common). Please update your question to specify that.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of steps involved ranging from trivial to more complex.  It depends on how the site was created, you don't say if it is a CMS or custom built.

First thing you will need is a working web server - [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) is open source, but not being a mac user I can't say whether it is the right tool for the job.  Once you know that it is running properly you need to get the files from godaddy.

You should use FTP and download the entire site.  This will give you all the files in the proper directories.

You also need to get the database.  I think godaddy uses PHPmyadmin: export the database(s).  Now you have everything you need.

Add the files you downloaded to the document root directory in your xampp installation.

Create the database and a user.  You will find the details somewhere in your site configuration files.  Import the SQL into the database.

You may have to adjust some of the connection information and file paths in the configuration file.

Comment: I'd only add that they likely should change any absolute URLs that use their domain to use `localhost` instead, or they can edit their _hosts_ file so that their domain will resolve to `localhost` - which is what I believe you meant by adjusting connection information and file paths.